# Excel VBA browser automation: website search box has no element id

Tags: excel, vba, browser, automation

I am trying to use Excel VBA for browser automation, but the website's (http://www.soccerstats.com/) search box has no element id, so the usual technique will not work. 
Here was my planned code:

```
    'dimension (declare or set aside memory for) our variables
Dim objIE As InternetExplorer 'special object variable representing the IE browser
Dim aEle As HTMLLinkElement 'special object variable for an <a> (link) element
Dim y As Integer 'integer variable we'll use as a counter
Dim result As String 'string variable that will hold our result link

'initiating a new instance of Internet Explorer and asigning it to objIE
Set objIE = New InternetExplorer

'make IE browser visible (False would allow IE to run in the background)
objIE.Visible = True

'navigate IE to this web page (a pretty neat search engine really)
objIE.navigate "http://www.soccerstats.com/"

'wait here a few seconds while the browser is busy
Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

'in the search box put cell "A2" value, the word "in" and cell "C1" value
objIE.document.getElementById("dsearch").Value = "arsenal"
```

The search box html code is:

`<input name="searchstring" style="border: currentColor; border-image: none; width: 90px; height: 20px; padding-left: 5px; background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238); text-color: gray;" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Search team...') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Search team...';}" type="text" maxlength="20" value="Search team...">`

Can anyone tell me how to put a value for this search box and then click the search button?

Comment: You will need [getElementsByName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752544%40v=vs.85%41.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You could loop through the input elements and find the one named `searchstring`, like this:

```
Dim ele As Object

For each ele in objIE.document.getElementsByTagName("input")
    If ele.Name = "searchstring" Then
        ele.Value = "Example Text"
    End if
Next ele
```

Comment: The `input` element has a [`name`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752544(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @Jordan I am also looking to click the button, I tried this but it didn't seem to work: For Each ele In objIE.document.getElementsByTagName("input")
    If ele.Name = "submit" Then
        ele.Click
    End If
Next ele

Comment: What is the HTML for the submit button?

Comment: '<input class="submit" style="border: currentColor; border-image: none; width: 25px; height: 20px; background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);" type="submit" value="Go ">'      It looks like no name? I got mixed up, submit is a class. Thank you

Comment: Managed to click the button! code hear incase anyone needs it. thanks again for help 'For Each ele In objIE.document.getElementsByTagName("input")
    If ele.className = "submit" Then
        ele.Click
    End If
Next ele'